# lsusb: unable to initialize libusb: -99

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, centos, libusb, lsusb

When I try to run `lsusb` I get the following error:

```
$ lsusb
unable to initialize libusb: -99
```

System details:

```
OS:         CentOS 6.5
Kernel:     2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
Installed:  libusb-0.1.12-23.el6.x86_64
            usbutils-003-4.el6.x86_64
```

These are all the standard installed packages. Why would this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I failed to mention that this system is a VM running under ESXi.  It turns out I didn't have any USB controllers configured for this machine, so `/dev/bus/usb` didn't even exist, which I believe is why `lsusb` was returning the error code.

The solution is simple: **Add a USB controller to the system.**

*I would consider this a bug in* `libusb` *or* `lsusb`. Wouldn't an error like `"No USB controllers detected"` be more helpful than some cryptic library-related error code?

References:

- [Re: fix for lsusb:unable to initialize libusb: -99](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/55080)